# Função com if e substring não está funcionando

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar uma função que ao executada verifica se a `substring` do valor de um `<input>` é igual à ***http://*** ou ***https://***, porém ela não está funcionando.

Tem algo errado com o código?

```
function goToWebsite() {
    var addressBarValue = document.getElementById('AddressBar').value;
    var frameSrc = document.getElementById('Frame').src;

    if ((addressBarValue.substring(0, 7) == "http://") || (addressBarValue.substring(0, 8) == "https://")) {
        frameSrc = addressBarValue;
    } else {
        frameSrc = "http://" + addressBarValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não funciona quer dizer q sempre cai no else? poderia dar um exemplo do valor de `addressBarValue`

Comment: Simplesmente não acontece nada nem usando os métodos que o @bfavaretto ensinou, não mostra erro no console, não cai no else, não muda o "src" do Frame...

Comment: Uma opção seria com regex: `if (addressBarValue.match(/^https?:\/\//)) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: Mesma coisa, o browser não mostra erro no console, não cai no else, etc...

Comment: Excluí minha resposta porque me enganei, o que eu disse estava errado. Na verdade, o código que você tem deveria funcionar... a não ser que haja espaços ou outro conteúdos antes do 'http...'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui fica mais uma resposta com uma outra abordagem.

Você pode usar o [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) com uma expressão regular (RegEx) para verificar o que precisa.

Teste assim: `addressBarValue.match(/https?:\/\//)`

```
if (addressBarValue.match(/https?:\/\//)) {
    frameSrc = addressBarValue;
} else {
    frameSrc = "http://" + addressBarValue;
}
```

A expressão procura ambos http e https e funciona assim:

`http` - a string exata 'http'
`s?` - opcional, pode existir ou não
`:` - corresponde a `:` literalmente
`\/` - corresponde a barra `/` mas precisa de ser escapada com `\` (2 vezes)

---

Em relação à sua variável `frameSRC`, você está a guardar uma string na variável, e não a apontar ao elemento para poder re-escrever o seu valor. Use assim:

```
var frameSrc = document.getElementById('Frame'); // tirando o '.src'
```

e mais tarde no `if/else` use `frameSrc.src = addressBarValue;`, ou mudando o nome da variável para `frame.src = etc...`

### O código final poderia ser:

```
function goToWebsite() {
    var addressBarValue = document.getElementById('AddressBar').value;
    var frame = document.getElementById('Frame');

    if (addressBarValue.match(/https?:\/\//)) {
        frame.src = addressBarValue;
    } else {
        frame.src = "http://" + addressBarValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: O problema era com a declaração da variável "frameSrc", tentei do seu jeito sem declarar e funcionou.

Comment: @JoséNeto, pois, editei a minha resposta para explicar isso. Fico contente que tenha resolvido o problema.